# Always loading saved data, and properly writing if function

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I need to load user data, but I need to do it looped. (always loading). My code is

```
NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
stringForKey:@"preferenceName"];
```

And also, whenever I make an if function, for example

```
if (t1activity == "active")
{

//code here

}
```

I get an error saying Expected identifier or '('

Thanks so much! (objective-c)

Comment: `if (t1activity == "active")` Missing a `@` to say that active a `NSString` => `@"active"`. Also, you are comparing pointers, not value => `if (t1Activity isEqualToString:@"active"])`? I don't know what you are doing with `savedValue` here.

Comment: I'm loading savedValue to know if the user created a test, (to study for) and then if they did, which is why i need the if statement, to create a certain view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case the value differs only between YES/NO is better to provide a BOOL.

```
BOOL isUserActive = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"preferenceName];
```

and the set method:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
 setBool:YES
 forKey:@"preferenceName"];
```

Then the decision is simpler:

```
if(isUserActive) {
{

//code here

}
```

I was curious to know, how often the NSUSerDefaults do update. Here the Apple Docs.

> NSUserDefaults caches the information to avoid having to open the user’s defaults database each time you need a default value. The synchronize method, which is automatically invoked at periodic intervals, keeps the in-memory cache in sync with a user’s defaults database.

Comment: Im curious, too. I want to know why it doesnt automatically refresh cached data...